# I cannot disable Laravel debug logging?

Tags: laravel, debugging, logging, config, laravel-7

I kept running the debug logging level for some time for my application also on prod, after now 2 weeks, I wanted to disable it. So I went ahead and opend the .env variable and set `APP_DEBUG=false`

I did a `php artisan down`, `php artisan cache:clear`, then `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan config:cache` and brought it back up. To be fully safe here.

I went back in the log file after a minute or so and still saw production.DEBUG appearing.
I then retried all the steps, checked the `config/app.php` file and made sure that nothing is wrong in there. But everything looks fine.

Then I went to my local environment and tried the same but to my surprise the application still keeps logging debug messages also on local!

I cannot get it disabled!

What I tried:

- php artisan config:clear / :cache / cache:clear optimize:clear / down / up ...
- I checked the app.php file, the config/logging.php but all looks fine
- APP_ENV=production, APP_DEBUG=false

Then to my surprise I tried something:

- I changed LOG_LEVEL=info in the .env file -> no change
- I opened the config/logging.php and went to the daily section (because LOG_CHANNEL=daily) and set the 'level' entry to 'info' => IT WORKS! both on PROD and LOCAL

  ```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'info',
        'days' => 21,
    ],
  ```

Can someone explain to me, why this is happening?
I was under the impression that the `APP_DEBUG` and the `LOG_LEVEL` should be the key indicators for Laravel but somehow they aren't?!

Might that be related to the LARAVEL DEBUGBAR? I have it installed.

Laravel version 7, php 7.4 (local Homestead, prod apache)

Comment: Just a thought, not sure if its a solution but, make sure that the APP_ENV is set to 'production' in your .env file :) Other than that, looks like you did all right.

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @zeppo Thanks for your hint, I forgot to mentioned it (updated the thread) - of course APP_ENV is set to production

Comment: @CanVural Tried that as well, no change..